# Symbol not found: _UnityGetAudioEffectDefinitions in Google VR SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

Here is the error that I get when trying to run Unity3D project (Sample Treasure Hunter) in XCode iPhone 5S simulator.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _UnityGetAudioEffectDefinitions
   Referenced from: /Users/romanmac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/333B47B5-B6BC-41E4-BD6D-611A9B4CE1DA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D8B8D3EF-F872-42F8-8407-3EC20B13474E/ProductName.app/ProductName
   Expected in: flat namespace
  in /Users/romanmac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/333B47B5-B6BC-41E4-BD6D-611A9B4CE1DA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D8B8D3EF-F872-42F8-8407-3EC20B13474E/ProductName.app/ProductName
 (lldb)
```

On device it works fine.

Unity 5.4.0f3 Personal Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014)

Here is settings for iOS player:

[image]

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: Similar issue.
OSx 10.10.5
xCode 7.2.1
Unity 5.5.2f1
GoogleVR SDK v?

Problem I was having:  app was crashing with this error  when trying to run in simulator and I couldn't get any further to do any sort of debugging.  Went into Plugins\iOS\CardboardAppController.mm and commented out lines 45-51: 
`//- (UnityView *)createUnityView {
`//  UnityRegisterViewControllerListener(self);
`//  UnityRegisterAudioPlugin(UnityGetAudioEffectDefinitions);
`//  UnityView* unity_view = [super createUnityView];
`//  createUiLayer(self, (UIView *)unity_view);
`//  return unity_view;
`//}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can modify `createUnityView` in your `CardboardAppController.mm` to:

```
- (UnityView *)createUnityView {
#if !TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
  UnityRegisterViewControllerListener(self);
  UnityRegisterAudioPlugin(UnityGetAudioEffectDefinitions);
#endif
  UnityView* unity_view = [super createUnityView];
#if !TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
   createUiLayer(self, (UIView *)unity_view);
#endif
  return unity_view;
}
```